# A normal minimal subgroup in a Sylow 2-subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$.  Let $N$ be a subgroup of $P$ of order two. If $|P|>8$, then is $N$ normal in $G$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match users' [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For any $\;n\ge3\;,\;\;Z(S_n)=1\;$ , meaning: the center of any permutation group of order $\;\ge4\;$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Could you explain a bit more? I don't understand the connection between them.

Comment: @M.Ramana Suppose $\;N\lhd G\;,\;\;|N|=2\;$ . What can you say about $\;N\;$ in relation to what I wrote?

Comment: I don't know. I just know we can embed $G$ into $S_G$.

Comment: @M.Ramana Suppose $\;1\neq n\in M\;$. What effect this element $\;n\;$ has under conjugation with **any** element $\;g\in G\;$ ?

Comment: Because $N$ is normal, so $n^g \in N$.

Comment: Since $|N|=2$, so for all $g\in G$, $n^g =n$, equivalently $gn=ng$.  This show that $N \subset Z(G)$.

Comment: @M.Ramana Exactly! So now you get a straighforward answer to your question...

Comment: But how ? I do not understand  how I can do it:(

Comment: @M.Ramana But you already did it! If $\;N\lhd G\;$ has order two, then it must be $\;M\le Z(G)\;$ . Yet $\;Z(S_n)=1\;$ for any $\;n\ge 3\;$ , contradiction...Thus there is no such normal subgroup!